# Delay between executing a SET command and saved data actually changing?

Tags: redis

For an application that I am building, we are using Redis as the session storage medium.

The other day, one of our testers noted that when he logged out and then *immediately* tried to access a protected URI (within about 1 second of logging out), his old session data was still being used.

Stepified:

1. User logs in as Account A.
2. User logs out.
3. User immediately accesses protected URI.
4. User is logged in as Account A again.

I think what is happening is this:

1. User logs out, so application clears the user's session and sends the empty session to Redis for storage.
2. Before the change "takes", the user accesses a different resource (e.g., the sign-in form or a protected URI).
3. The application requests the session from Redis, which still contains the logged-in session values.
4. The application sends the updated session back to Redis, overwriting the logged-out session.

Is this a correct diagnosis?  Does Redis have a delay between accepting a `SET` and actually updating the stored value?  Or should I be investigating something in my application logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no delay in the execution of SET command. If redis-server returns successfully, and your client library reports a success - you can be sure that redis has written the data.

I'd recommend looking at your application stack. Perhaps the session handler is invalidating sessions asynchronously?